# URL Rewriting is not working

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

/var/www/html/cmdbsep.htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^link.html$ add_server_admin.php?id=$1
```

I have made the following Entry in httpd.conf file

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/cmdbsep">
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

But still its not working

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve, but you you try to add the backreference $1 to the URI but you don't define it

Comment: @Reeno that I was just try to test as it isn't working, so I was just simpllifying it and checking for any error. As per my understanding it should work with the simplest of URL

Comment: But what if you removed the error causing code by simplifying it? Anyway, you didn't describe exactly what goes wrong. Do you get an error message (Status 500 maybe) or does your URL not get rewritten and you get the status 404? Or something else?

Comment: If i add garbage value then it is giving the error 500.

Comment: But if you don't add garbage you get 404? If yes, your regexp is wrong. It's very hard to help you if we don't know all the details...

Comment: @Reeno if I don't add Garbage I am not getting any error. Just the URL is not rewriting. I added the Garbage to check whether the filel is being read or not.

Comment: Then mod_rewrite is working, but your regexp is wrong. And without the exact regexp we can't help you.

Comment: Ok but if my regexp is wrong then also this should work "RewriteRule hehehe.html searchhost.php" but even this isn't working

Comment: @Reeno when i am opening localhost/cmdbdep/hehehe.html directly its working but when I am clicking on a link to open it it isn't opening as hehehe.html but as localhost/cmdbsep/add_server_admin.php?id=22

Answer (score 0):

Based on "/var/www/html/cmdbsep.htaccess" I'm assuming that you have a file called cmdbsep.htaccess in the /var/www/html/ folder.  Instead, you want to create a folder /var/www/html/cmdbsep and in that folder create a file called .htaccess

Don't forget to restart Apache to apply your config changes:
apachectl restart

Comment: .htaccess files don't need apache restarts

Comment: But changes in *httpd.conf*

Comment: Hi Lumberjack,                                                       my filel is /var/www/html/cmdbsep/.htaccess only

Comment: Yes @Reeno my httpd.conf file is having bellow entry

<Directory "/var/www/html/cmdbsep">
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>

Comment: when i am opening localhost/cmdbdep/hehehe.html directly its working but when I am clicking on a link to open it it isn't opening as hehehe.html but as localhost/cmdbsep/add_server_admin.php?id=22